# Unable to print the value of cells upto the last row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to print the content of column A. There are 10 rows in there, so when I try like the following I get the results accordingly:

```
Sub PrintUptoLastRow()
    Dim oCel As Range

    For Each oCel In Range("A1", "A10")
        Debug.Print oCel
    Next oCel
End Sub
```

I can get the same results without hardcoding the last row:

```
Sub PrintUptoLastRow()
    Dim oCel As Range

    For Each oCel In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Debug.Print oCel
    Next oCel
End Sub
```

The above two methods are identical as long as the last row is `A10`.

However, I can also get the results using:

```
Sub PrintUptoLastRow()
    Dim oCel As Range

    For Each oCel In Range("A1:A5")
        Debug.Print oCel
    Next oCel
End Sub
```

But things go wrong when I try to mimick the above using last row:

```
Sub PrintUptoLastRow()
    Dim oCel As Range

    For Each oCel In Range("A1" & ":" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
       Debug.Print oCel
    Next oCel
End Sub
```

It throws the following error:

```
Run-time error `1004`
Method `Range` of object`_Global` failed
```

***How can I make the last piece of code work the way I tried?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forgot an `A` and `row`:

```
For Each oCel In Range("A1" & ":A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

or you use the `address` property

```
For Each oCel In Range("A1" & ":" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)
```

But be aware that you always refer to the ActiveSheet.

Comment: Yeah, address property is what I missed. Thanks.